# htaccess condition in 301

Tags: php, .htaccess, conditional-statements

I am sure there are other threads on similar topics around the web. But I just can't get this working on my own website. Please help me

My site working in my subdomain

for eg `http://demo.example.com/sitename/india`

if i am put 1 parameter like (india) only. its loading `profile.php?countryname=india` also its working good.

But when i add multiple parameters into my url like this

`http://demo.example.com/sitename/india/tamilnadu/chennai`

i want load `profile.php?countryname=india&state=tamilnadu&city=chennai` .

I am try this code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^demo\.example\.com/sitename$
RewriteRule (.*) walola/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ sitename/profile.php?countryname=$1&state=$2 [QSA]
```

When i pass single parameter into my url its working otherwise its shows 404 error.

Please guide me.

```
***Answer***

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^demo\.example\.com/sitename$
RewriteRule (.*) sitename/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+) [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ sitename/profile.php?countryname=$1&state=$2 [QSA]
```

Its Works good.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ sitename/profile.php?countryname=$1&state=$2 [QSA]
```

or else send the full url to the `profile.php` page and split by using php.

i.e.,

```
RewriteRule ^/* sitename/profile.php?site=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: What is a mean by [L,NC,QSA]. also how can i parse my params. please tell me

Comment: You can get the detail for all the flags in the following link http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html. and you can get the full url i.e http://demo.example.com/sitename/india/tamilnadu/chennai in your profile.php page in $_GET["site"]. There you can split by using explode function in php

Comment: Thanks for your response. But i have one problem. please help me

Comment: Please see this url demo.osiztechnologies.com/carrental/Italy/Cagliari-#ca#. my base url is demo.osiztechnologies.com/carrental but all links are change. and css path also change please help me

Comment: Please define the base url in the configuration file and use that in the css url

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
1. RewriteRule ^sitename/(.*) /sitename/profile.php/$1 [QSA,L]
2. In PHP: $args = explode("/", $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]);
3. By var_dump($args) you will have idea how to deal with it.
```